# No module named gevent

Tags: python, pip, gevent, easy-install

I am having a lot of problems with missing modules in Python on my Mac. I think a lot of it has to do with miss matched versions of python installed on the machine.

I am trying to run some python script which imports GEVENT module. The system Tells me there is no module named GEVENT to be imported.

When i Open Python and import Gevent I get the same error.

I have tried to install GEVENT using PIP and Easy_Install but when I try using pip or Easy_install I get this error:

```
$ easy_install gevent

-bash: /usr/local/bin/easy_install: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Can any one assist?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your installation of python is broken. easy_install does not find your python binary. If you fix that, you will then be able to install `gevent`.

(In other words, your problem has nothing to do with `gevent`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198346/no-module-named-gevent-even-though-it-is-installed any thoughts here ^.