# no module named gevent even though it is installed

Tags: python-2.7, gevent

OS : Ubuntu 16.04
Python 2.7

```
pip list | grep gev
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
gevent (1.3a2)
```

Just to make sure, I checked:

```
  pip install --upgrade gevent
Requirement already up-to-date: gevent in /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: greenlet>=0.4.13; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" in /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent)
```

However when I actually run my python program it bails out with an error:

```
 import gevent
ImportError: No module named gevent
```

Please advise.

Stuff I already tried:

```
pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)


python -m pip install --user gevent
Requirement already satisfied: gevent in /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.13; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" in /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent)

which -a python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

along with things mentioned here:
https://github.com/PokeAlarm/PokeAlarm/issues/22

I also tried uninstalling the pip installation and doing apt-get :

```
sudo apt-get install python-gevent python-gevent-websocket
```

mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836029/importerror-no-module-named-gevent/1013457#1013457

Comment: Much discussed. How the Python interpreter is finding libs is different from where pip is putting them, probably. Make sure you exhaust the research tips already captured in places like https://stackoverflow.com/q/32680081/1531971

Comment: I already tried it.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04: `pip install gevent` `Requirement already satisfied: gevent in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages` `Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.10 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent)` `import gevent` works successfully.

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K tried _what_ exactly? There is a lot of chatter about this very common problem, and we don't know what you have tried. External links do not count; they will be dead in no time, making this Q&A less useful to others in the future. As it stands you have a very common set of symptoms with a few causes. What research have you done to isolate  and work from the known  to the unknown? At the end of the day, either Python cannot find that installed module, or the module cannot be found using that name or symbol.

Comment: At the end of the day, tweaking `PYTHONPATH` in the same shell you run Python would go a long way to proving or disproving a huge chunk of potential root causes here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working in a Python virtual environment in Ubuntu 16.04 I got the following results:

```
$ python -m pip install gevent 
Requirement already satisfied: gevent in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages  
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.10 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent)
```

`import gevent` worked successfully in my Python virtual environment, but it did not work outside of my Python virtual environment until I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt install python-gevent # also works in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu
```

Description: gevent is a coroutine-based Python networking library.  gevent uses greenlet to provide a high-level synchronous API on top of libevent event loop.

You can also install python3-gevent for Python 3.x in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install python3-gevent
```

Answer (score 4):

make sure that your pip references the same python that you are using,
on many systems you can have multiple python versions installed.
you can see which to which python your pip belongs by running:

```
pip --version
```

Comment: it says pip --version pip 9.0.1 from /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGxdQ.png)

goto anaconda navigator and select the environment on which you are working ...then select not installed ,check for gevent and install

Answer (score 0):

Delete `gevent` library by browsing through `Lib/site-packages`

Try the install command `pip install gevent`